# How do i restrict tasks between roles i.e admin and users in express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my project I have two roles

they are 
 admin and
 user

and my requirment is, i have to restrict the users tasks like admin can only add users but eventhough logged as user  i can able to post. I has to overcome this problem can any one help me. I am using express.js, mongodb server side, client side angular.js

Here is my code

adduser function:

```
exports.adduser = function(req, res) {
    delete req.body.roles;

    var user = new User(req.body);
    var message = null;
// Add missing user fields
    user.provider = 'local';
    user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
       //send mail to user
agenda.now('New_User_Create_Notify', {data:user.username});
res.jsonp(user);



        }
    });
};
```

route:::

```
app.route('/auth/adduser').post(users.adduser);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have got users roles set

you can do this in adduser function

```
if(req.body.roles.indexOf("admin") == -1){
return res.status(403).send({
                message:"user doesnt have required permision"
            });
}else{
   user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
       //send mail to user
agenda.now('New_User_Create_Notify', {data:user.username});
res.jsonp(user);

  }
```

}

Comment: Thnks for replying, I am getting an error like this "cannot cal method indexof undefined" added this too but cannot solve my problem exports.adduser = function(req, res, io)